# Java GUI Mouse Listener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouselistener

could you guys help me out.

How do we order the process of `Mouselistener`?

I mean, I want my `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` working after I click on my one of my `JPanel`.

Comment: Please explain a little bit better what you want.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not to clear.
actually I'm about to create a program that consists of 5x5 panels. 
How the program works is first I have to click on one of the panel. when i click it, the color of that panel will change(exp. green). after that first click, wherever I move my mouse, the panel that I pass should change color as well(exp. yellow).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to enable a `MouseMotionListener` only after a component is clicked...

Basically, in your `MouseListener`'s `mousePressed` method, you would simply add your `MouseMotionListener`

Now remember, mouse listeners consume events, that is a child component will hide mouse events that occur on it from it's parent container

Take a look at [How to write mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

Comment: You gotta love blind down voting, it doesn't allow people to learn or give them the opportunity to improve their answers :P

Comment: Speculation:  It *could* come from a new attitude sweeping SO Meta that 'poor questions' should be down-voted and closed/deleted, rather than answered (whether well or any other way).  Perhaps someone extended that down vote to an answer as well.  But that is just my random speculation.  It would be good to get actual information to replace it.